# Kendo UI One DataSource for Multiple Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui

I have an issue with Kendo UI lately, I have 1 datasource and it is used by 3 grids. This is all working but for some reason styling of the grid is "dismantled" for a lack of better word.

If I filter the datasource from Grid A, Grid A looks good but Grid B and C would look something like this (don't mind the firstname "Error" in the column):

[image: Grid B and C]

If I filter the datasource from Grid B, Grid B now will look good but Grid A and C will look "dismantled". What could be the problem?

Grid A:

```
    $('#grid-a').kendoGrid({
      autoBind: false,
      dataSource: emp_ds,
      toolbar: kendo.template($("#mainlist-template").html()),
      scrollable: true,
      sortable: true,
      selectable: 'row',
      pageable: {
        input: true,
      },
      columns: [{
          field: "id",
          title: "ID",
          width: 100
        },{
          field: "firstname",
          title: "Firstname"
        },{
          field: "lastname",
          title: "Lastname"
        }
      ]
    });
```

Grid B:

```
    $('#grid-b').kendoGrid({
      autoBind: false,
      dataSource: emp_ds,
      toolbar: kendo.template($("#emplist-template").html()),
      scrollable: true,
      sortable: true,
      selectable: 'row',
      pageable: {
        input: true,
      },
      columns: [{
          field: "id",
          title: "ID",
          width: 100
        },{
          field: "firstname",
          title: "Firstname"
        },{
          field: "lastname",
          title: "Lastname"
        },{ 
          command: {
            text: 'Select',
            click: function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              if(employeeSelectSwitch == 2) {
                return;
              }

              varholder.curUid = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr").data('uid');

              $('#daterange-dialog').data('kendoWindow').center().open();
            }
          },
          width: 140
      }]
    });
```

DataSource:

```
emp_ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url.employeeList
      }
    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          id: { type: 'number' },
          firstname: { type: 'string' },
          lastname: { type: 'string' },
        }
      }
    },
    pageSize: 15
  });
```

Comment: code could be very helpful to analyze your problem

Comment: I updated the post for the code, sorry about that.

Comment: Are you sure that it has to do with `DataSource` and `Grid`? It looks to me like a styling problem. Do you have some fixed height for the `Grid`?

Answer (score 0):

Jest thinking why you need 3 grids to display Same Data , Use 3 Datasource if you are not sharing the datasources. tale a look @ Kendo Shared Datasource .

Answer (score 0):

If you really want just one datasource that executes once, and you can't share it because each will be filtered differently,

You could populate the datasource in the background, and when the data comes back, split it amongst the grids like so:

```
 var dsBackground = new kendo.data.DataSource(myDsConfig);

 dsBackground.read().then(function (e) {
    if (dsBackground.data().length > 0) {
        $(".parallel-grid").each(function() {
            var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
            if (grid != null)
            {
                dsBackground.filter({ field: "foo-type", operator: "eq", value:$(this).data("foo-type")});
                grid.dataSource.data(dsBackground.view());
                grid.dataSource.page(1);
                grid.dataSource.pageSize(10);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a working sample with some fake data:

http://dojo.telerik.com/@paltimus/EmUXE/2