# kendo ui one dataSource with multiple grids, charts and grouping

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-chart, kendo-datasource

I would like to generate several grids and charts with one kendo dataSource. It is important that the grids and charts can be grouped independently.

Example: If I group the column "age" in "grid1", you only want to group in "grid1".
In the example all applications are grouped.

My goal:

- grid1 grouped by age
- chart1 grouped by Name
- grid2 not grouped
- chart2 not grouped

Enclosed I have an example code: https://dojo.telerik.com/uPuqO/22

Thanks for your help

Severin

Comment: There is a good idea to generate the views: [Kendo UI One DataSource for Multiple Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042958/kendo-ui-one-datasource-for-multiple-grid). But i find no way to update the data. My experiance to upgrade data: [http://dojo.telerik.com/itulU/4](http://dojo.telerik.com/itulU/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you bind to local data. Create an array of objects, then assign the same array to all of your grid datasources.